# How can I get get my Index to work in MySQL when FORCE INDEX is not working?

Tags: mysql, indexing

MySQL refuses to use INDEX. I am new to inedexing (first time) and I dont know what to do to make MySQL use the index. I only have 32000 rows or so, and it only has to return 177 rows.

I have tried other queries where it returns more rows hoping for a different outcome. I even tried using "FORCE INDEX" and it also doesnt work. Is there a setting that needs to be turned on or something? I am confused and stuck.

`CREATE INDEX idx_area_code ON USHouseholdIncome (Area_Code) ;`

then I use use EXPLAIN and FORCE INDEX as shown below.

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM USHouseholdIncome FORCE INDEX (idx_area_code) WHERE Area_Code = 203 ;`

| type | possible_keys | key | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SIMPLE | idx_area_code | NULL | 31483 | 10.00 | Using Where |

This is what I get when I use EXPLAIN and FORCE INDEX on my table USHouseholdIncome. As you can see it sees my index idx_area_code but it chooses not to use it for some reason.

I think it is using the primary index instead of the one I created. Any workaround for this?

INSERT INTO was used for each row using JSON I think which was already done for me when creating this table. Hopefully this helps

Comment: can you please show the CREATE TABLE

Comment: I had to import the table using JSON because importing the data via csv was not working. Does that help?

Comment: json wouldn't used the index see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html and that is vital information, better would be to see why your import of the csv faild, a new question with a sample of your csv and maybe a download of a sample

Comment: What is this index cardinality?

Comment: Oh, wow, Im sorry I did not know that was vital information, thank you for letting me know. I appreciate your help. Learned something new.

Comment: The index cardinality was the same as the rows because it was using the primary index instead.

Comment: How do I show my question as answered?

Comment: you need to provide the answer and then accept it

Comment: not clear what "using JSON" means, and doesn't seem to me like any of the comments actually answered your question.  please do edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table USHouseholdIncome` and at least one sample data row.

Comment: How many rows in the table?  How many rows have area_code = 203 (do a select to find out; don't trust Explain).  How long does the query take with FORCE and without?